# Can we use the sub for updating the password in AWS cognito instead of using username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, reset-password

I am having one doubt, i am having some problems with the username in cognito, so i am trying to update the password with sub, but it is showing "user doesn't exist" error, can we update the password with any other attributes in cognito other than username

Need to update the cognito password using sub other than username

Comment: can you show us some code?